# CXF maven wsdl2java plugin not generating toString() methods in the generated jaxb classes

Tags: cxf

I have used CXF maven plugin in my project which converts wsdl file to appropriate Java classes. But I don't see toString() method in the generated Java classes. Can you please let me know how to generate toString() method. Below is the snippet of my pom.xml which I've used in my project:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.trx</groupId>
  <artifactId>resxWebservices</artifactId>
  <version>10.4.1</version>

  <name>resxWebservices</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <sourceRoot>src</sourceRoot>
              <wsdlOptions>
                <wsdlOption>
                  <wsdl>./resxWebservices.wsdl</wsdl>
                  <extraargs>
                    <extraarg>-xjc-Xts</extraarg>
                  </extraargs>
                </wsdlOption>
              </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-ts</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <executable>${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
          <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-xjc-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-xjc-ts</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 10):

I believe first you have to make your pom little clutter free.

You need to have 2 dependency to get the `toString()` method generated. Both you are using. Only mistake you are doing is to have `cxf-xjc-runtime` in your `cxf-codegen-plugin` dependency. 
Remove this from  said location.
And put it in module/project dependency.
It will start working. Below is the example snippet:

```
<dependencies>
    ....
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-xjc-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/generated</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/../someService.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-xjc-Xts</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>
                            </wsdlOption>                               
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-xjc-ts</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

After doing this, you will have result like below:

```
/**
 * Generates a String representation of the contents of this type.
 * This is an extension method, produced by the 'ts' xjc plugin
 * 
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, JAXBToStringStyle.DEFAULT_STYLE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this example is a working one with lattest libraries