# NoClassDefFoundError when using cxf-codegen-plugin with maven

Tags: maven, wsdl2java, cxf-codegen-plugin

I'm trying to convert wsdl into java using maven and cxf-codegen-plugin but i always get the same error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.1.6:wsdl2java (aspsms) on project webapp: org/apache/velocity/context/Context: org.apache.velocity.context.Context -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.1.6:wsdl2java (aspsms) on project webapp: org/apache/velocity/context/Context
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: org/apache/velocity/context/Context
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.generate(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:435)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractCodegenMoho.execute(AbstractCodegenMoho.java:260)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.execute(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:512)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/velocity/context/Context
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.AbstractGenerator.<init>(AbstractGenerator.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.generators.AbstractJAXWSGenerator.<init>(AbstractJAXWSGenerator.java:30)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.generators.AntGenerator.<init>(AntGenerator.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.getFrontEndGenerators(PluginLoader.java:278)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.getFrontEndProfile(PluginLoader.java:393)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.loadFrontEnd(WSDLToJava.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.generate(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:415)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.velocity.context.Context
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 38 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My mvn version:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: /Users/user/Desktop/dev/ses/apps/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_101, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Here is my pom file:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>aspsms</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/generated-source</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/wsdl/aspsmsx2.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>com.test.service.adapter.aspsms.wsclient</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The jar files were correctly downloaded in my maven repo. Do you have an advice?

Comment: Maybe this working example will help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40158135/3779152

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add explicitly the dependency to velocity in the plugin configuration

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>aspsms</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/generated-source</sourceRoot>
                    <wsdlOptions>
                        <wsdlOption>
                            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/wsdl/aspsmsx2.wsdl</wsdl>
                            <extraargs>
                                <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>com.test.service.adapter.aspsms.wsclient</extraarg>
                            </extraargs>
                        </wsdlOption>
                    </wsdlOptions>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
                    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```